# Powershell not able to access packages / "NuGet" package provider after security configuration update

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, powershell

I updated a server with a mof / dsc configuration, essentially changing various permissions / registry keys for security compliance. This was autogenerated to some degree, I do have a list of everything that was configured, but it's a bit difficult to read and not exactly clear.

After the process, powershell cannot update new packages, or set its default repository.

I dont think this is something specific to NuGet, and my hunch is that it is related to some kind of more basic file permissions. NuGet is, for all I can tell, installed on my system, I know for a fact it was installed prior to applying this configuration, and form what I can tell was not removed.

I have double checked a working server, and the permission on the NuGet .dll look the same.

Here is an example of an error:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Register-PSRepository -Default
PackageManagement\Import-PackageProvider : No match was found for the specified search criteria and provider name
'NuGet'. Try 'Get-PackageProvider -ListAvailable' to see if the provider exists on the system.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:7302 char:25
+ ...     $null = PackageManagement\Import-PackageProvider -Name $script:Nu ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (NuGet:String) [Import-PackageProvider], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForCriteria,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.ImportPackageProv
   ider


NuGet provider is required to continue
PowerShellGet requires NuGet provider version '2.8.5.201' or newer to interact with NuGet-based repositories. The NuGet
 provider must be available in 'C:\Program Files\PackageManagement\ProviderAssemblies' or
'C:\Users\opc\AppData\Local\PackageManagement\ProviderAssemblies'. You can also install the NuGet provider by running
'Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force'. Do you want PowerShellGet to install and import
 the NuGet provider now?
[Y] Yes  [N] No  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"): Y
PackageManagement\Install-PackageProvider : Unable to find repository with SourceLocation ''. Use Get-PSRepository to
see all available repositories.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:7405 char:21
+ ...     $null = PackageManagement\Install-PackageProvider -Name $script:N ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.Power...PackageProvider:InstallPackageProvider) [Install-Pac
   kageProvider], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RegisterPackageSourceRequired,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPack
   ageProvider

PackageManagement\Import-PackageProvider : No match was found for the specified search criteria and provider name
'NuGet'. Try 'Get-PackageProvider -ListAvailable' to see if the provider exists on the system.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:7411 char:21
+ ...     $null = PackageManagement\Import-PackageProvider -Name $script:Nu ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (NuGet:String) [Import-PackageProvider], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForCriteria,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.ImportPackageProv
   ider

PackageManagement\Get-PackageProvider : Unable to find package provider 'NuGet'. It may not be imported yet. Try
'Get-PackageProvider -ListAvailable'.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:7415 char:30
+ ... tProvider = PackageManagement\Get-PackageProvider -Name $script:NuGet ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.Power...PackageProvider:GetPackageProvider) [Get-PackageProvi
   der], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnknownProviderFromActivatedList,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.GetPacka
   geProvider

Register-PSRepository : NuGet provider is required to interact with NuGet-based repositories. Please ensure that
'2.8.5.201' or newer version of NuGet provider is installed.
At line:1 char:1
+ Register-PSRepository -Default
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Register-PSRepository], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotInstallNuGetProvider,Register-PSRepository
```

Package Providers on a working system:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-PackageProvider -ListAvailable

Name                     Version          DynamicOptions
----                     -------          --------------
msi                      3.0.0.0          AdditionalArguments
msu                      3.0.0.0
NuGet                    2.8.5.208        Destination, ExcludeVersion, Scope, SkipDependencies, Headers, FilterOnTag...
PowerShellGet            1.0.0.1          PackageManagementProvider, Type, Scope, AllowClobber, SkipPublisherCheck, ...
Programs                 3.0.0.0          IncludeWindowsInstaller, IncludeSystemComponent
```

Package Providers on broken system (note, nuget is no longer capitalized, odd, also the directory for "NuGet" is lower case, not sure if thats relevant:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-PackageProvider -ListAvailable

Name                     Version          DynamicOptions
----                     -------          --------------
nuget                    2.8.5.208
```

NuGet package files (DLL is indeed in here, I tried replacing it with the DLL from a working system to no avail)

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> gci -Recurse -Filter "nuget" -Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Path "C:\"


    Directory: C:\Program Files\PackageManagement\ProviderAssemblies


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----        2/10/2020   5:03 PM                nuget
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was fips!!! oh my word that was a tough one.

Here's the registry key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\FIPSAlgorithmPolicy

Here's were I found my solution: 
https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/15126048-install-packageprovider-name-nuget-not-working